# Мне нужно чтобы выводилось имя человека в дискорде, но выдаёт ошибку. Что делать?

Tags: python, бот, discord-api, discord.py

@bot.command(pass_context=True)

async def kill(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):

```
await ctx.send('{member.mention}  {}'.format(ctx.message.author.mention))

await  ctx.message.delete()
```

Ошибка:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'member'

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kill(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention}  {ctx.author.mention}')
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]